# How do I enable the rulers on Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, user-interface

I've seen some Layout Editors in Android Studio with a ruler on top and on the side for the Preview window and I'm trying to figure it out how to enable, any ideas? I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I can't see them.

[image]

Comment: Looking for the same.

Comment: Please upvote the question for visibility

Comment: found any way??

Comment: I guess they just quietly removed the feature from Android Studio 3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the ruler has been removed from the `Preview` tab of the Layout Inspector since Android Studio 3.0. It's 2020 now and Android Studio 4.0 has a new `Layout Validation` tool to preview the layout on different devices and display configurations. Not really the same but at least the Layout Inspector seems much more reliable than those days.

More details at: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#layout-validation

Answer (score 1):

The Guidelines *are* the rulers. You move them around to get the measurements you need. Expressed in percentages or units.

Comment: Guidelines certainly helps but are limited to ConstraintLayouts, the rulers on the image of the question used to be available for all layouts.